# Get ClientID in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a javascript file that Select a button using jQuery and check it for validation.the code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#<%= btn_Insert.ClientID %>').on("click", function (event) {

    if (Validate() != true) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
function Validate() {
    return (1 == 1);
});
```

but I can' get `ClientID` for button and I get this Error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

where is my mistake?How I can get Client ID for a server side Button?

thanks

**EDIT 1)**

When I add script in `head` part of page it works but when I write it to a JS file and add reference to it in `head` part it does not work

Comment: does it have `runat="server"` defined on it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that the error comes from the fact that `event` has a special meaning in some browsers. Try renaming the variable:

```
function Validate() {
    return (1 === 1);
}

$(function () {
    $('#<%= btn_Insert.ClientID %>').on('click', function (evt) {
        if (!Validate()) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

or even easier :

```
$('#<%= btn_Insert.ClientID %>').on('click', function() {
    return Validate();
});
```

---

UPDATE:

Now that you have edited your question it is clear where the problem is. You are trying to use server side tags (`<%= %>`) in a separate javascript file. That's impossible. They will render literally and will not be processed by ASP.NET.

In order to solve your issue you could apply a CSS class to the button and then use a class selector:

```
$('.someClass').on('click', function() {
    ...
});
```

Another possibility is to use the [ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

```
$('[id$="btn_Insert"]').on('click', function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: @Nima, ohh, I see now. You are using ASP.NET server side tags in a separate javascript file which is impossible. I have updated my answer  to suggest you a workaround using a class selector instead of an ID selector.

Comment: is It possible to use regular expression for selecting my button?I this way `find all element that ends with "btn_Insert"`? how I can write this such selector?

Comment: @Nima, yes it is possible, simply use the [ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/): `$('[id$="btn_Insert"]')`.

Answer (score 0):

http://jagregory.com/writings/how-to-use-clientids-in-javascript-without-the-ugliness/

Comment: I use your link and add this line: `var btn = '<%= btn_Insert.ClientID %>' ;  alert(btn);`; and the message is `'<%= btn_Insert.ClientID %>'` :(

Answer (score 0):

Just add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to your server button control and use its ID in js w/o problems:

```
$('btn_Insert').on('click', function() {
    return Validate();
});
```

Comment: My control is in the master page and I don't want to set `ClientIDMode="Static"`

Comment: It won't work if you put getting of ID in separate JS file; therefore, just put in head getting of control's ID (`var btn = '<%= btn_Insert.ClientID %>'`) and on external JS file use this variable.